# ExecutorService: how to prevent thread starvation when synchronization barriers are done in the threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I have a situation for which I am having troubles to find a clean solution. I'll try to explain as detailed as possible.

I have a tree-like structure:

```
NODE A
    NODE A.1
    NODE A.2
        NODE A.2.a
        NODE A.2.b
    NODE A.3
        NODE A.3.a
        NODE A.3.b
        NODE A.3.c
NODE B
    NODE B.1
    NODE B.2
```

I need to process the root node:

```
 public void process(final Node node) { ... }
```

The process of a node involves two things:

```
- some database queries
- the process of all children of these nodes
```

In other words, once `NODE.2.a` and `NODE.2.b` are processed, `NODE.2` can be processed. I am processing the nodes in a recursive fashion, nothing spectacular.

So far, so good. Now I want to declare a global executor service, with a fixed number of threads. I want to process the child nodes of a node in parallel. So, `NODE.2.a` and `NODE.2.b` can be processed each in their own threads. The code would look something like this:

```
// global executor service, shared between all process(Node) calls
final ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

public void process(final Node node) {
    // database queries
    ...

    // wait for children to be processed
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(node.children().size());

    for (final Node child : node.children()) {
        service.execute(() -> {
             process(child);
             latch.countDown();
        });
    }
    latch.await();
}
```

The problem here is: when a certain depth is reached, all threads are halted in the `latch.await()`. We have reached a situation of thread starvation.

This can be easily solved by making the executor service unbounded, but I don't like that option. I want to control the number of `active` threads. In my case, the number of `active` threads will be equal to the number of cores. Having more `active` threads will introduce swaps from one thread to another, and I would like to avoid that.

How can this be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is technically a deadlock.
We first think of deadlock as when two or more processes are awaiting on locks but in this case the threads are waiting on each other.
Interestingly its a way of producing the strange beast of a self deadlock. If you have a pool of one thread it will submit tasks and wait on them but never execute because it's waiting on itself to finish to execute them!

The standard answer is called a 'Work Stealing Thread Pool'.
I came across exactly the same issue and without that piece of vocabulary took ages to find any information on what I quickly worked out was a common problem in any recursive algorithm that is executed in fully concurrent recursion.

OK, this is a sketch of how it works.
Create a fairly standard thread-pool with one trick.
When a thread reaches a point where it cannot proceed without the results of a queued item, check if that item has been started by another thread and if it hasn't then execute it in the current thread (rather than waiting), otherwise wait on the thread executing that item to finish it.

It's very simple but may require you to build your own thread-pool class because off-the-shelf solutions often don't support it.

Do beware of course that a typical non-trivial recursive algorithm will breakdown into many more sub-tasks than you have parallel processing units.
So it may make sense to enqueue subtasks to some level and then just execute the remainder in a single thread.

That is unless enqueuing and dis-enqueuing items is cheap you can spend time putting items in a queue to take them back. Those operations may be serialised amongst the threads and reduce parallelism. It's hard to use lock-free queues because they don't usually permit extraction from the middle of the queue (as required here). You should limit how deep you go parallel.

On the plus side, notice that executing a task in the currently executing thread involves less task swapping overhead than parking the current thread and (at the OS level) swapping in another worker.

Here is a Java resource that provides a `WorkStealingThreadPool`.
Please note I have made no effort to evaluate the implementation and offer no recommendation. I've been working in C++ in this case or would happily share my `template`.

https://www.jrebel.com/blog/using-java-executors

Also refer to what Wikipedia has to say: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_stealing

Comment: Very interesting, thank you. The term 'work stealing pool' was indeed very useful, which made me end up to the fork join pool starting from JSE7. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html. This looks exactly what I needed. I'll first test it out.

Comment: @BasOpers You're very welcome and I'm pleased to meet a fellow traveller. I tried asking this question and people who didn't understand the problem just kept saying I was over complicating a thread pool. I'm already learning something that Java has this built in. In many ways library provision in C++ is in its infancy in concurrency. I'd love to hear about your outcomes.

Comment: I got it working with the ForkJoinPool from JSE. It's pretty straight forward. In the parent, for every child, I am forking the execution of the child to a new task. At the end of this loop, I am joining all these child executions before I return. I will now start analysis of performance. Thanks again for your insights, these were VERY helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I would not use error-prone multiple CountDownLatch-es. As I understand you want to traverse tree from leafs nodes to parent nodes in parallel.

I would traverse tree using simple BFS/DFS (you don't need recursive algorithm there), once leaf is found without children nodes, put this node it into blocking the queue.

The queue can be polled by second thread, this thread will schedule new task to the executor service with fixed number of threads.

Once executor-thread finishes processing current node taken from the queue, executor-thread checks whether current node has parent nodes. If there is a parent node, put it in a queue again. Also you should check whether parent has been already processed.

Something like this:

```
    BlockingQueue blockingQueue = new BlockingQueue();
    ExecutorService service = 

    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        while (true) {
            Task task = blockingQueue.poll();
            service.execute(new Runnable(){
                if (task.isProcessed())  {
                   return ; 
                }
                ... do you job
                task.setProcessed(true);
                Node node = task.getNode();


                boolean allChildrenProcessed = true;
                for (Node childeNode: node.getChildren()) {
                    allChildrenProcessed &= childeNode.isProcessed();
                }

                if (node.hasParent() && allChildrenProcessed) {
                    blockingQueue.put(node.getParent())
                }

            });
        }
    }).start();

    Stack stack = new StackImpl();

    stack.put(root);
    while (node = stack.pop() != null) {
        for (Node child: node.getChildren()) {
            stack.push(child);
        }
        if (node.getChildren().isEmpty()) {
            // add leaf node for processing
            blockinQueue.add(node);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Actually you don't really need polling thread, you can put tasks directly to executor

Comment: I like the idea for custom BFS/DFS, but my question was more on the 'concurrent' side than the 'tree parsing' side. The tree-like structure was mainly for illustrating the problem. I upvoted anyway, because it is a clever idea.

Comment: @BasOpers Well propsed design will allow to traverse tree concurrently. There is no special pill for handling similar 'concurrent' task, it's all about finding proper algoritm. Mentioned work-stealing approach won't help you, until you know how to parrallel your algoritm.

Comment: Actually, I do know how to parallel my flow. Every child node can be processed in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

It seem like you want an alternative to recursion. That alternative is scatter-gather. Submit a request that forks all Tasks. When NODE.2 executes, it simple returns since the child nodes have not completed. When the last Task completes (2.1, 2.b), completion processing begins to process NODE.2.

I maintain a Data Parallel open-source product that can do exactly that. Rather than fetching the entire product, simply download the documentation (http://coopsoft.com/JavaDoc.html ) and look at file: Manual/DynamicJoin.html. If that solves your problem, then you fetch the product.

Comment: Thank you. The scatter-gather: what is the difference between the fork join pool from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html?

Comment: @Bas Opers All the difference in the world. join() doesn't work for one. You could try using the CountedCompleter class if you could figure out how to use it. I wrote a series of articles on the framework starting here: http://www.coopsoft.com/ar/CalamityArticle.html

Answer (score 0):

What you really want could be achieved using

```
int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cores);
```

Remember also that [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#getActiveCount%28%29) of getActiveCount() says that it is an approximate number.

Answer (score 0):

`newFixedThreadPool()` uses `LinkedBlockingQueue` when the pool is full.

That queue is **unbounded** by default, which means any tasks received after filling up the capacity of the thread pool will be queued for execution for when pool has more available slots.

And `CountDownLatch#await()` will not do busy-wait, it should put the awaiting thread out of the CPU.

So, your problem is basically that you'll exhaust all available threads, and are not reusing them, so no new threads can be created.

All you need here to solve the issue is to slightly modify the default behavior of the `newFixedThreadPool()`. You can create a thread pool with a queue of limited size, and adapt the behavior of that thread pool in case the queue gets full to reuse the running queue for executing the new task.

```
ExecutorService executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(4,
                     4,
                     0L,
                     TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
                     new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(4),
                     new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());
```

See [CallerRunsPolicy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy.html), [ArrayBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html).